Caddy PHP fastcgi not giving server script_name when handle_path is used
Caddy (2.8.4) is hosting a PHP application through FastCGI (PHP-FPM) but for some reason the $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] does not contain the full path when I use the caddy handle_path config.
:80 {
    handle_path /subpath/* {
        # serve a PHP site through php-fpm:
        php_fastcgi localhost:9000 {
            root /var/www/html
        }
    }
}

When I visit:
www.domain.com/subpath/ I get:
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=/index.php

But I would like to get /subpath/index.php
How should I change the caddyfile config to achieve this?

I just faced the same problem, and found your question! In the end, while Caddy's behavior is different from Apache and nginx, it's easy to set SCRIPT_NAME explicitly as you prefer, as it's just an environment variable:
:80 {
    handle_path /subpath/* {
        php_fastcgi localhost:9000 {
            root /var/www/html
            env SCRIPT_NAME /subpath{path}
        }
    }
}

